# Run a validation based on enum value in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

I am working on a rails app and want to validate some fields based on `enum`. This is what I tried. But am getting some errors

```
         class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base

              enum status: [:draft, :published]

              scope :draft,     -> { where status: :draft     }
              scope :published, -> { where status: :published }

              validates_presence_of :attribute1, :attribute2, :attribute3, unless: "status.draft?", on: :update

           def publish!
            self.update status: :published
           end
         end
```

All my `status` fields have a `default value of 0` which will be `draft`. When I   `update` a listing am getting this error.

> undefined method `draft?' for "draft":String

Its happening during the `@listing.update(params)`. Could someone tell me what am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call enum method, you should not call method from `status`. just call from object.

It means that do not call `@listing.status.draft?`, call `@listing.draft?`

so, do `unless: 'draft?'` instead of `unless: 'status.draft?'`

and also you do not need to define scope for status. It automatically define scope methods for enum.

Read doc: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Comment: Really helped mate..Thanks for the info..Never used enums before and was wondering what am doing wrong...Thank you...